# How to plot GeoTIFF using tmap in R?

Tags: r, r-raster, tmap, rnaturalearth

A simple plotRGB leads to the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eaH9.jpg) while plotting with tmap returns [only a blue-shaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNcBo.jpg). What am I doing wrong?

**original image**
[image: original-image]

**blue-shaded image**
[image: blue-shaded-image]

Code snippet:

```
library(raster)
library(tmap)
library(rnaturalearth)

ne_download(scale = 50, type = 'HYP_50M_SR_W', category = 'raster', destdir = getwd())
rst <- brick("HYP_50M_SR_W/HYP_50M_SR_W.tif")

plotRGB(rst) # works

tmap_mode("plot")
tm_shape(rst) + tm_rgb() # does not work
```

Using: R version 3.5.1, RStudio 1.1.456, tmap 2.1-1, raster 2.6-7, rnaturalearth 0.1.0

Answer (score 1):

It might be working now, note the warning though:

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
library(tmap)
#> Warning: package 'tmap' was built under R version 3.5.2
library(rnaturalearth)
#> Warning: package 'rnaturalearth' was built under R version 3.5.2

ne_download(scale = 50, type = 'HYP_50M_SR_W', category = 'raster', destdir = getwd())
rst <- brick("HYP_50M_SR_W/HYP_50M_SR_W.tif")

plotRGB(rst)
```

[image]

```r
tm_shape(rst) + tm_rgb()
#> Raster object has 58320000 (5400 by 10800) cells, which is larger than 1e+07, the maximum size determined by the option max.raster. Therefore, the raster will be shown at a decreased resolution of 1e+07 cells. Set tmap_options(max.raster = c(plot = 58320000, view = 58320000)) to show the whole raster.
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> - Session info ----------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
#>  os       Windows 7 x64 SP 1          
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United States.1252  
#>  ctype    English_United States.1252  
#>  tz       Europe/Berlin               
#>  date     2019-01-30                  
#> 
#> - Packages --------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package       * version   date       lib source        
#>  assertthat      0.2.0     2017-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  backports       1.1.2     2017-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
#>  base64enc       0.1-3     2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
#>  callr           3.0.0     2018-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  class           7.3-14    2015-08-30 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  classInt        0.2-3     2018-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  cli             1.0.1     2018-09-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  codetools       0.2-15    2016-10-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  colorspace      1.3-2     2016-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  crayon          1.3.4     2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  crosstalk       1.0.0     2016-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  curl            3.2       2018-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  DBI             1.0.0     2018-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  desc            1.2.0     2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  devtools        2.0.1     2018-10-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  dichromat       2.0-0     2013-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
#>  digest          0.6.18    2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  e1071           1.7-0     2018-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  evaluate        0.12      2018-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  fs              1.2.6     2018-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  glue            1.3.0     2018-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  htmltools       0.3.6     2017-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  htmlwidgets     1.3       2018-09-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  httpuv          1.4.5     2018-07-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  httr            1.3.1     2017-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  KernSmooth      2.23-15   2015-06-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  knitr           1.20      2018-02-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  later           0.7.5     2018-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  lattice         0.20-35   2017-03-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  leaflet         2.0.2     2018-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  lwgeom          0.1-5     2018-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  magrittr        1.5       2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  mapview         2.6.0     2018-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  memoise         1.1.0     2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  mime            0.6       2018-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  munsell         0.5.0     2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  pkgbuild        1.0.2     2018-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  pkgload         1.0.2     2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  png             0.1-7     2013-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
#>  prettyunits     1.0.2     2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  processx        3.2.0     2018-08-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  promises        1.0.1     2018-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  ps              1.2.1     2018-11-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  R6              2.3.0     2018-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  raster        * 2.8-4     2018-11-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  RColorBrewer    1.1-2     2014-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
#>  Rcpp            1.0.0     2018-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  remotes         2.0.2     2018-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  rgdal           1.3-6     2018-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  rgeos           0.4-2     2018-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  rlang           0.3.0.1   2018-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  rmarkdown       1.10      2018-06-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  rnaturalearth * 0.1.0     2017-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  rprojroot       1.3-2     2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  satellite       1.0.1     2017-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  scales          1.0.0     2018-08-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  sessioninfo     1.1.1     2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  sf            * 0.7-1     2018-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  shiny           1.2.0     2018-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  sp            * 1.3-1     2018-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  spData          0.2.9.4   2018-09-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  stringi         1.2.4     2018-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  stringr         1.3.1     2018-05-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  tmap          * 2.2       2019-01-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  tmaptools       2.0-1     2018-08-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  units           0.6-1     2018-09-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  usethis         1.4.0     2018-08-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  viridisLite     0.3.0     2018-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  webshot         0.5.1     2018-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  withr           2.1.2     2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  XML             3.98-1.16 2018-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  xml2            1.2.0     2018-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  xtable          1.8-3     2018-08-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
#>  yaml            2.2.0     2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```